# How do I find/replace rows in oracle having text containing % and other special characters

Tags: oracle

Gurus, I have huge data with 540K rows and one of the field is Customer Address. Our system doesn't accept special characters '% | ^ \ /' in the address field.

Here is my query that works. How do I make it work for all the special characters in single update query?

`select regexp_replace(address,'%',' ') from temp where address like '%\%%' escape '\';`

```
update temp set address=regexp_replace(address,'%',' ') where address like '%\%%' escape '\';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update temp 
set address = regexp_replace(address,'[%|^\/]',' ') 
where regexp_like(address, '[%|^\/]')
```

Comment: Shame on me :(.That was pretty simple!